# remove dots from value

Tags: shell-script, centos, awk, services

I am trying to write a script that shows me if a service is running or not.
command:
`service ntpd status | awk '{print $5}'`
output:
`running...`
how can i remove those dots? or is there a better way to find out that a service is running or not?

Comment: You could use `sed` to remove the dots. However, `service name status` *is* a script that tells you if a service is running or not. Not sure why you would need something else.

Comment: What do the dots matter? That command gives you want you want which is the status of the service.

Comment: its going to be shown in a monitoring program. i don`t know how to do that with sed. i never used sed befor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the awk's `gsub` command:

```
$ service ntpd status | awk '{gsub(/[.]/,"");print $NF}'
running
```

Using `NF` since the status word is usually the last word of the output.

The command `service` is the old way to check services (for systems not using systemctl yet). With systemd use:

```
systemctl is-active sshd >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo YES || echo NO
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with below  sed command and it worked fine

```
@praveen_linux_example ~]# service sshd status| sed "s/\.//g"
openssh-daemon (pid  2268) is running
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on `sed`:

```
service ntpd status | sed 's/^.* \|\.*$//g'
running
```